# HTTP POST Request XML File Contents in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an xml file that I need to post the contents of to a url.  From that url I will then be retrieving the contents, making objects out of the xml structure and writing them to a database.  The second part is essentially already done, but I'm struggling with the first half.  I need to write it in Powershell and have 0 experience in that.

filename: TestResults.trx
url to post: (whatever, but I'm using a reqeustbin url to test now)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Version of PowerShell? Any code that you've already tried that failed? Help others help you :)

Comment: Search SO for "powershell post"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more specifics I would point you to the help for `Import-Clixml` and `Invoke-WebRequest` for starters.

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` worked just fine.  Thanks.  After looking at the documentation for it I was able to figure it out.